# Is there anyway to use the Google Drive API to list which files are sharable to anyone with a link or are publicly searchable?

Tags: google-drive-api

I currently have a lot of files in Google Drive and would like to programmatically find which ones might be available to the web or available to those with the link of a file. I'd like to search which files were set to "Anyone with the link" or "Public on the web". The picture below shows this. Is there a way to easily list this with the Drive v3 API?

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `I'd like to search which files were set to "Anyone with the link" or "Public on the web".`, when you want to retrieve such files in your Google Drive, you can use the method of Files: list in Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) How about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to call [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and use the search query parameter (`q`) to list only the files with certain `visibility` settings. For example, if you want to retrieve both the files shared with `anyone with link` and `anyone on the Internet`, you can set `q` the following way:

```js
q: "visibility='anyoneCanFind' or visibility='anyoneWithLink'"
```

[From the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms):

> **visibility (=, '!=')**: The visibility level of the file. Valid values are anyoneCanFind, anyoneWithLink, domainCanFind, domainWithLink, and limited.

#### Note:

- The rest of parameters provided to `Files: list` will depend on the exact search you want to make (from your Drive, from a shared Drive, etc.). I'm assuming this is not part of your question.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms)